# php cURL PATCH Request returning data but not updating field

Tags: php, curl

I'm using PHP and cURL to access an API and am currently trying to update a field. My request is working properly, because the request responds with an array of the the properties of the ID I am attempting to change, however it won't change the field I need it to. I'm not sure if it has something to do with having to use PATCH to access this command in the API, and using POSTFIELDS to update the field, but I've seen other posts on stack overflow do this.
My code:

```
    $jsonStr = "{'field_37' : '$lastPaid'}";
    $post_url = "https://api.APISITE//v2/entity_objects/$ID?access_token=$accesstoken";
    $curl = curl_init($post_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonStr);
    $post_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $response = json_decode($post_response,true);
    print_r($response);
```

I've double checked that the syntax of my jsonStr is correct, and it exactly matches what is needed on the RESTAPI to update field_37.
I tried using json_encode on $jsonStr but that didn't make a difference either.